# PHP: How to post on user's wall as appliaction when he is not logged in right now?

Tags: php, facebook

I downloaded the PHPSDK from
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk
and managed to create a login into facebook for my webpageusers with:

```
$loginUrl=$facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array(
        'req_perms'=>'publish_stream,offline_access',
        'next'=>$nexturl,
        'cancel_url'=>'http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_failure.html',
        'connect_display'=>'popup'      )
    );
```

How do I post on a facebookusers wall, when he is not logged into facebook or my website anymore?

```
$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed','post',$attachment);
```

only posts on the actual logged in users wall.

Comment: @DampeS8N It is possible, that's what the `offline_access` permission is for - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

Comment: Guh, one more reason never to sign into anything with FBC.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try replacing `me` with the actual user's ID? I.e. `$facebook->api('/user_ID/feed','post',$attachment);`

You might also need to include the access token explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't used the PHPSDK from a long time ago, but in order to post with offline access using /me/feed you have to pass in the parameters the access_token, the access_token can be obtained from the facebook cookie of the user when he login to facebook and grants offline access. So in order to make api calls when the user is not logged you should store the facebook user id and the access_token of the user you want whenever you can and use it instead of the current user session that is visiting the site.

I suggest that you do something like the following:

```
#your code above
$attachment['access_token'] = $the_access_token;
$facebook->api('/$user_id/feed',$attachment);
```

Hope it works!!, I can't test it sorry :S
and sorry for the broken english too.